# Is there any way to connect to MS SQL Server 2008 using Management Studio 2005?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Is there any way to connect to MS SQL Server 2008 using Management Studio 2005?

Comment: upvoted because this seems to be a common question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see:

[FIX: You may experience problems when you use SQL Server Management Studio in SQL Server 2005 to connect to an instance of SQL Server 2008](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946127)

(specifically SQL Server 2005 SP2 Cumulative Update #5)